# Magento - Images are not showing on Firefox

Tags: html, css, magento, firefox

On our magento category pages, I have added a static block at the top. This static block contains 3 images.

The 3 images appear on Chrome and Internet Explorer. But on Firefox, none of the images show.

On chrome and IE, the code displays the 3 images and it looks like this:

```
<p>
<a href="">
    <img width="250px" height="135px"  src="/img1.jpg" />
</a>

<a href="">
    <img width="250px" height="135px" src="/img2.jpg" />
</a>

<a href="">
    <img width="250px" height="135px" src="img3.jpg" />
</a>
</p>
```

But on firefox, it adds the class="qluzuqkroyuyuepwnuwm" on the img tags.

```
<p>
    <a href="">
    <img class="qluzuqkroyuyuepwnuwm" width="250px" height="135px"  src="/img1.jpg" />
</a>

<a href="">
    <img class="qluzuqkroyuyuepwnuwm" width="250px" height="135px" src="/img2.jpg" />
</a>

<a href="">
    <img class="qluzuqkroyuyuepwnuwm" width="250px" height="135px" src="/img3.jpg" />
</a>
</p>
```

I have no idea what that class is or why it gets added on there only on firefox.

Does anyone have any ideas on why a class gets added on firefox only, and why the images don't show?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

God, I am an idiot.

Adblock was turned on and it blocked my images /facepalm

Really sorry everyone, I thank anyone who read this post or brief investigation.

Comment: Don't worry, I've fallen into that trap too. The thing is Adblock will block what it "thinks" are ads, and part of that is if they have sizes that are typical of an ad (or a name that includes a size typical of an ad).